# App to browse and copy files from other devices via bluetooth for Android?

Tags: gratis, android, file-synchronization

I need a app for Android through which I could browse and get files on other phones via Bluetooth.

#### Compulsory features:

- Should browse Android phones
- Ability to get any files from the phone
- Versions between at least 2.3 to 4.2 of android must be supported
- Free (as in cost)
- Either of English or Hindi language support

#### Features I would like:

- Browse other OS phones (Java, Symbian, iOS etc)
- GUI
- Available via play store

#### Plus points for these:

- FOSS
- Wifi Direct, NFC support